# How do `Map<String, String>` get to know, the `String` endings in `MethodChannel` arguments

Tags: string, flutter, file, dart

If dart and kotlin code communicate through binary(array of 8-bit integers (0-255)), then how does `String` end or even `int` end is represented in, or determined from binary sequence of bytes, is there some special charCode or something else.

Also is there a way to save a `List<int>` as-it-is to a `file.txt`, so it can be read directly to `List<int>` instead of serialization.

Please guide this new dev,
Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Flutter handles the `MethodChannel`, in both the Dart side and Kotlin side, it can be allowed to have its own internal protocol to communicate between the native layer and Flutter. In theory they could use JSON but they are probably using something else based on the supported types and also making it more efficient: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab#codec

For saving a `List<int>` to a file, you need to determine how you want to encode the content in the file and then how you want to decode it. It can be as simply as just saving each number separated by comma or encode the list into JSON.

If your list of numbers can be represented with `Uint8List` or `Int8List`, then you can basically just save the numbers as raw bytes to the file and then read them again.

But `List<int>` is a list of 64-bit numbers and you should therefore determine how you want to encode this exactly.

For writing to files, there are several ways to do it but the specific way depends on what you exactly want. So without any more details I can just suggest you check the API: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-io/File-class.html

Comment: hello, @julemand101 may i ask that, is there a way to send binary data (Uint8List) directly to kotlin side, instead of some codec or utf-8, thanking you

Comment: @gitman-2021 Did you read the first link? MethodChannel supports sending `Uint8List` which will be received as `ByteArray` in Kotlin.

Comment: im asking that, not using `StandardMessageCodec()`, but absolutely raw (no codec, plain Uint8List), as performant as possible

Comment: Don't know much about this area but I found https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/BinaryMessenger-class.html in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/binaryMessenger.html

Comment: anyone interested in this may read the comment block starting at line 250 at [github.com](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cd41fdd495/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart#L250)